# Why my ccAnimation not working on device?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, device-emulation

I have simple CCAnimation loading from playlist, and when i test it on emulator everything is OK, but when test on device animation didn't play?

Can some body tell me where will be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that device is key sensitive, so if your file real name is MyAnimation.png then loading myanimation.png works on the simulator but NOT on device.

Anyway, as YvesLeBorg said, some code or log will help.

Comment: Exactly this was the problem! There was key sensitive difference between plist files, I fix it before days but, thank you for good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

a bit of code would help, maybe a log from the device. Chances are either your plist or your texture did not make it to the device. Try 1) ensure your plist and texture are included in the target, 2) cleaning the target, build and run.